# echoing basename under xargs?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, xargs

I have the following command :

```
ls /some/path/*dat | xargs -n 1 -I @ sh -c "echo `basename @`"
```

with the directory `/some/path/` containing :

```
/some/path/a
/some/path/b
/some/path/c
/some/path/d
```

I want to get the output :

```
a
b
c
d
```

But I'm still getting full paths. What am I doing wrong ?

edit: BTW, I know that there is an easier way, I can just run `basname` instead of

```
echo `basename @`
```

But I need to run a complex command, something like

```
octave --silent --eval "somefunction('`basename @`','@',...))"
```

edit2:

Here is the actual command :

```
 ls ~/phd/data/conll2012/dev.megam/*dat | xargs -P 16 -n 1 -I@ timeout -k 1s 15m sh -c "if [ ! -f '~/phd/xp/conll2012/dev.megam/@.$epsilon$mink$minn$alpha' ]; then octave --silent --eval \"xprp('~/phd/xp/conll2012/dev.megam/@.$epsilon$mink$minn$alpha.rp','@',$alpha,$mink,$minn,$epsilon);\" 2>> ~/xpgrid.log;fi"
```

Basically, I have a set of files in a directory and this command feeds on these files to output result in another directory, checking if the result is not already there.

So, I need both files with fullpath and files with only basename.

How to make it work on ? The easier example at the beginning can help make this clearer.

Comment: Why not just `find /some/path/ . -name "*dat" -exec basename {} \;`?

Comment: Why not just `for file in path/*dat; do ...; done` eliminating `ls` altogether?

Answer (score 4):

```
ls /some/path/*dat | xargs -n 1 -I @ sh -c 'echo `basename "@"`'
```

The `basename` is executed too early in your code.

If you are not sure that there are no spaces or tabs in the paths then you should use `-d \\n` (or `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...`) and mind the `"` around the `@`.

Comment: Or `-printf '%f\0'` if using GNU `find` so you don't even need `basename`. `(cd /some/path && printf '%s\0' *dat)` would probably even make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

The testcase can be fixed simply by changing the double quotes to single quotes, but you might like to know about GNU `parallel`.

You can do the same thing like this:

```
parallel echo {/} ::: /some/path/*dat
```

(You may need to quote the curly braces, in some shells.)

As well as having clearer syntax, `parallel` will run the multiple commands at once.

Your second example would look like this:

```
parallel octave --silent --eval "\"somefunction('{/}', '{}', ...)\"" ::: /some/path/*dat
```

(You have to have quotes within quotes because it gets evaluated twice.)

Comment: I believe the last command can be quoted using `-q` thus getting rid of \"

Answer (score 2):

```
 # find all my perl file names with *.pl or *.pm ext sorted 
 find src/ -name '*.pm' -o -name '*.pl'  \
  | xargs -n 1 -I @ sh -c 'echo `basename "@"`' | sort
```